# Argument to deal with

Tags: complex-analysis

How can  we deal with this argument 
$$\arg\left ( \frac{i+e^{i\Theta x} }{i-e^{i\Theta x }}\right )^{2}$$ 
Where $\Theta \geq 0$
This argument come from a hard integral  after take the real part which I stopped at this point and can't complete

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:**

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{i+e^{i\Theta x}}{i-e^{i\Theta x}}&=\frac{(i+e^{i\Theta x})(-i-e^{-i\Theta x})}{|i-e^{i\Theta x}|^2}\\\\
&=\frac{-i2\cos(\Theta x)}{|i-e^{i\Theta x}|^2}
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: This will become $(arg(cos\Theta x-\frac{\pi}{2}))^{2}$ how I can find the argument for this?

Comment: Is it equal to pi^2/4?

Comment: Assuming theta and x are positive?